# Regex filter is not filtering out network calls/traffic on Charles Proxy when correct regex is used

Tags: charles-proxy

In Charles Proxy, I want to identify all traffic that is not from my test environment so I can easily delete it. When I save my Charles Proxy session, I want it to be as small as possible (and then attach the session file to a JIRA ticket). Currently, JIRA only does not allow files > 30MB and Charles Proxy session files are generally a lot bigger than that.

If I copy and paste the 5 network calls listed below into [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and want to find all network calls that do NOT contain the word "charles", the following regex query correctly finds 4 lines:

> /^((?!charles).)*$/mg

5 sample network calls

> - https://www.googleapis.com  200 CONNECT www.googleapis.com      Wed Sep 05 17:29:30 AEST 2018   666862  72162   Complete
> - https://clientstream.launchdarkly.com/mping 200 GET  clientstream.launchdarkly.com  /mping  Wed Sep 05 17:29:30 AEST
>     2018  360975  25111   Complete
> - https://www.charlesproxy.com    200 CONNECT www.charlesproxy.com        Wed Sep 05 17:29:29 AEST 2018   6101    22034   Complete
> - https://www.googleapis.com  200 CONNECT www.googleapis.com      Wed Sep 05 17:29:30 AEST 2018   726122  23941   Sending request body
> - https://app.launchdarkly.com/msdk/eval/users/qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm 304 GET app.launchdarkly.com    /msdk/eval/users/qertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm  Wed
>     Sep 05 17:29:31 AEST 2018 41  29204   Complete

However, when I enter that same regex query into the filter field on Charles Proxy, it doesn't actually filter out anything. FYI, I have already checked the "Filter uses regex" checkbox in Charles Proxy (via the "Settings" button on the filter bar).

Does anyone have any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I figured out a solution that works for me. If you go to Record Settings -> Include and then enter which location(s) you want to record/include. The Session file I save is now only a few KBs (it used to regularly be 50+ MBs)

Answer (score -1):

An answer of some sort, the `^` doesn't work in Charles 4.2.X. The good news, it works in Charles 4.3b1. The bad news, it isn't available yet but should be available next week. It you remove the `^` your regex should work in 4.2.X.